# Creating Wordpress Widget - $wpdb not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a simple wordpress widget to display the amount of offers and bonuses available on my website. Unfortunately, it seems to be crashing, like something is missing.

Here is my code:

```
        // Block direct requests
    if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    die('-1');


add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
     register_widget( 'MatchedBettingBonusCount' );
}); 

/**
 * Adds MatchedBettingBonusCount widget.
 */
class MatchedBettingBonusCount extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'MatchedBettingBonusCount', // Base ID
            __('MatchedBettingBonusCount', 'text_domain'), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'My first widget!', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        $sqlOfferCount = "SELECT * FROM vhyky_posts WHERE post_type =  'cs_cause' AND post_status =  'publish'";
        $sqlOfferSum = "SELECT sum(vpm.meta_value) FROM vhyky_posts vp, vhyky_postmeta vpm WHERE post_type = 'cs_cause' AND post_status =  'publish' AND vp.id = vpm.post_id";

        global $wpdb;
        $offerCount = $wpdb->get_results($sqlOfferCount);
        $offerSum = $wpdb->get_results($sqlOfferCount);


        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo __('We currently have <strong>'.$offerCount. '</strong> sign-up offers. Totalling an amazing <strong>&pound;'. $offerSum .'</strong> of bonuses' , 'text_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

} // class My_Widget
```

A lot of the stuff I have been trying seems to be out of date. Currently the value just says **array**

Comment: `$wpdb` doesn't appear magically in your function, you have to use `global $pwdb;`.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I have included this before, $sqlOfferCount but it is still causing the same issue

Comment: Well, as long as you don't post actual error messages it's just blind guessing.

Comment: and remove the `or die(mysql_error())` functions ... wordpress doesn't use them, the only thing they'll do is try to connect to a local database with default credentials that hopefully don't work.

Comment: It's not giving an error, it's just a blank white screen when trying to access wp-admin. I have removed the or die functions. Thanks again for your patience

Comment: Then turn on error reporting or look at the error logs of your server.

Comment: I have error_logs on, but for some reason nothing is writing out to it. If I remove the plugin wordpress loads. So, I know it's something I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add aggregate function to count your offers (change in the first query).
Second, you need to change `get_results` to `get_var` since you only have 1 variable returned and `get_results` by default returns and array of objects.

Here's the changed code:

```
    $sqlOfferCount = "SELECT count(*) FROM vhyky_posts WHERE post_type =  'cs_cause' AND post_status =  'publish'";
    $sqlOfferSum = "SELECT sum(vpm.meta_value) FROM vhyky_posts vp, vhyky_postmeta vpm WHERE post_type = 'cs_cause' AND post_status =  'publish' AND vp.id = vpm.post_id";

    global $wpdb;
    $offerCount = $wpdb->get_var($sqlOfferCount);
    $offerSum = $wpdb->get_var($sqlOfferCount);
```